# Google BigQuery API force MaxResult

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-explorer

I am trying to run a query on BigQuery table and store the the result in locally.

`getQueryResults` API has `maxResult` parameter. Which says I can specify maximum number of rows to fetch. However, even after specifying it to **10,000** it fetches only few rows and in random manner.

If I specify it to small number, i.e. 10, then it works perfectly fine.

**is there a way I can force to fetch 10,000 rows ?**

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults

Answer (score 0):

`getQueryResults` returns up to `maxResult` rows in the response. If it returns fewer rows, you need to pass the `pageToken` returned in the response to another `getQueryResults` call in order to fetch the next page of rows from the server.

The [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) implement paging so that you don't need to do this yourself

Comment: Thanks. is there any way I get all the pageTokens? as sequential run would take too much time. Thinking to do parallel call using threading.

Comment: No, you need to fetch the pages iteratively.